# Поиск API - онтопик или у нас нет?

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Собственно вопрос - в заголовке.

Пробовал на en-SO [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194768) задать - получил минусы, закрытие и предложение на другом сайте задать вопрос. Задал на [другом](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/191985) - закрыли вопрос модераторы.

А у нас? Что думаете - стоит такое задавать?

Comment: перефразируй вопрос из поиска апи, в _как сделать то-то_ :-)

Comment: @Grundy, хм, а это мысль)

Comment: Я думаю, проблема просто в формальном подходе к закрытию вопросов. Данная причина закрытия предназначена для вопросов, касающихся рекомендации продуктов, а не любого "поиска API". Если вопрос просто о том, какой раздел конкретного GooglePlay developer API выполняет какую-то задачу, он конечно не должен закрываться.

Answer (score 7):

Вообще, https://android.stackexchange.com/ - это про вопросы именно пользовательский. По крайней мере, последний раз когда я там был, там нельзя было задавать именно программерские вопросы.

А вот почему вопрос закрыли на SO - это странно. Понятно, что они попытались подвести под причину "Вопрос о поиске книг...", но как-то, meh.

У нас такой вопрос вполне уместен, как по мне.

Comment: Вот да, злые они там все(

Comment: можно на /tour посмотреть, чтобы узнать какие вопросы можно задавать: https://android.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @jfs "Have a programming question? Visit our sister site, Stack Overflow" (:

Comment: на SO совершенно правильно закрыли: как "вопрос о поиске библиотек". На подобные вопросы, малоинформативные быстро устаревающие списки ссылок обычно дают в качестве ответа -- для этого гугл существует (жаль что на ru.SO убрали эту причину закрытия). Вместо *"какую библиотеку использовать для обширной темы A"* лучше задать вопрос "как сделать конкретную вещь X"

Comment: @jfs а он что сделал? "Как получить список покупок?" "Как получить статус?" Куда конкретней то?

Comment: я вижу вопрос: *"Is there API for developers earnings from PlayMarket apps?"* а не "how to..."

Comment: @jfs и вместо того чтобы переформулировать вопрос, они его просто закрыли.

Comment: @Suvitruf если вы не боитесь намерение автора исказить, то сами переформулируйте (это его в очередь по переоткрытию переместит, если я не ошибаюсь)

Comment: Я боюсь, что даже переформулирование вопроса на "как получить" не поможет, т.к. мне просто ответят что мол надо API искать) А я его честно много часов искал - не нашёл(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб переформулировка порой [выручает](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41359232/revisions). А при сомнениях, где задавать вопрос, можно написать на MSE с меткой [site-recommendation].

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я вообще предлагаю расширить онтопик сайта, очень много полезных тем обрезаются.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, тут надо очень аккуратным быть - можно полностью растерять уникальность, потонув в смежных с программированием вопросах(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб согласен, сразу делать это не правильно, но можно начать с обсуждения, так как эта тема уже давно просится, взвесить, посмотреть все за и против, возможно в начале сделать как экспериментальную функцию

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, ну, я на днях попробую такое у нас спросить и посмотрим как сообщество отреагирует) А то вот зарубежные участники очень даже не приветствуют такое(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб но у них есть другие сайты сети. Кстати я понял в чём моя ошибка, я написал предлагаю расширить, это неверная формулировка, из-за этого и путаница, что меня обычно в таких предложения не понимают. Правильнее сказать - предлагаю обсудить расширение онтопика. Это я больше себе.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, в данном конкретном случае, к сожалению, мой вопрос подразумевает ответ ссылку - боюсь, что такой ни на каком сайте сети задать не получится)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хм, я видел реальные вопросы на которые приводились в качестве ответа список ссылок, и никто даже и не думал закрывать или минусовать. Правда там были ссылки с описанием. Ссылку не приведу. Конечно не говорю что сейчас так будет, сейчас эта тема обострена. Кроме того это может быть не ответ а комментарий, а в комментариях ссылки разрешены, и даже если вопрос пометят требующим правки то комментарии остаются открытыми.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, да, я собственно и рассчитывал хотя бы на ссылку в комменты, но так и не дождался. У нас постить немного опасаюсь - всё ж вопрос не совсем хороший получится, а я модератор и должен, по идее, примером служить, а не переоткрывать свои оффтопичные вопросы)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб лично я даже если не за расширения онтопика сайта на всё IT, то поиск библиотек по моему мнению это чисто программисткий вопрос, потому что есть вещи где нету никакого смысла изобретать велосипед, и самописный код будет на 90% хуже готового. Есть вещи требующий целой команды и долгого времени на разработку.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а где-то в справку входит что поиск API это запрещённая тема? Если нет тогда эта тема напрямую попадает под вопросы по программированию. В списке закрывашек тоже нет такой формулировки для закрытия.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  например парсинг HTML на C#. Это просто было бы нереально глупо не пользоваться готовыми парсерами, и делать это вручную. И по моему мнению вполне логичный вопрос, какие есть парсеры на C#.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин если из html нужно выцепить всего 1 поле, то достаточно обычной регулярки самописной. Зачем целую либу тащить? Так что, it depends.

Comment: @Suvitruf согласен, просто я имею ввиду что есть задачи где без готовой библиотеки не обойтись, либо это можно но будет стоить неимоверных трудов и это просто нецелесообразно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Видел на SO RU вопрос, минусов нету ни за вопрос ни за ответ, закрывашек тоже не было. Человек спрашивает вполне нормальную вещь, конвертер markdown, самому такой конвертер написать нереально сложно и смысла нет в обычной ситуации. И что такие вопросы закрывать?